# Capture hexadec color code with javascript match function

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm tring to capture the hexadecimal colour code of the background-color of an element with javascript. I use this script:

```
style = select.find(":selected").attr("style");
match = style.match(/background-color ?: ?(#[0-9a-f]{6})/i);
console.log(match);
```

The code above results in match array has two elements:

```
0: "background-color:#f"
1: "#f"
```

And I can't figure out why does my regex capture only '#' and the first actual character of the 6 char long hexadec code. I have tried to add the '**g**lobal' modifier but still the same result. How should my regex look like?

Here is a example about what I want:
From any kind of inline css definition something like: 
"`border:1px solid #00ffff; background-color: #00ffaa; width: 500px ...etc`" match the "`background-color: #00ffaa`" part and extract the "`#00ffaa`" part.

Comment: why not use jquery and use $(el).css('background-color')?

Comment: It could be because It is expecting 6 of #[0-9a-f] rather than 6 of [0-9a-f] after a #.  You could try just explicitly bracket that part, i.e. #([0-9a-f]{6}), to ensure the 6 is bound to the [0-9][a-f].  Also  you should match on capital letters A-F too.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you going to do with the color you get back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```js
var string = "border:1px solid #00ffff; background-color: #00ffaa; width: 500px ...etc";

var answer = string.match(/background-color\s*:\s*([^;]+)/);

console.log(answer);

document.write(answer[0] + '<br>' + answer[1]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There's no need to parse the entire style string with regexp, in fact it's a horrible idea. Just get the value of the `background-color` property.

Comment: @torazaburo. The problem is, look here: _http://jsfiddle.net/cb6jdhy5/_ the browser returns hex as rgb. :(

Comment: @torazaburo. Then, at this point I should disagree that regex isn't better.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely to be better ways to accomplish what you are trying to--which is what?

I presume that you want to find the color of some element because it means something--such as, if the background is blue, it's the sidebar, or if the button's background is gray, it's disabled, or in your case, if the selected option is pink, then it's a dog. In essence, you're storing part of the state of your application in CSS properties. But as you've found, once you've set the CSS it may not be trivial to get it back out again. So the most basic solution is to see if there's a way to manage the state of the application in JS.

In your case, you seem to be wanting to get the background color of the selected option in a `select` element, in order to do something with it. Consider instead maintaining an array of relevant information for each option; or putting a data attribute on each option that you get easily; or some other approach that does not require rummaging around down inside the style string.

Second, experienced HTML/CSS folks pretty much agree that using individual style properties is less preferable than using classes. With classes, I can set a bundle of properties on an element just by setting the class; and I can easily query, remove, or replace classes with standard DOM or jQuery APIs.

Third, it is also pretty much agreed that using regexp to parse languages--even one as simple as CSS--it not a good idea. You'll always miss something, and then your regexp will break. For instance, in your original regexp, and the one in one of the answers, the regexp will not work unless there is exactly zero or one space around the colon. Some poor soul--perhaps you, perhaps some new guy coming in six months from now--is going to have to track down and fix the bug that will arise when someone puts two spaces after the colon.

Or you will assume that the background color is always set using a hex value--and build your code on that assumption. But then the new guy comes along and decides to specify a color using `hsl`--and again the code will break.

Fourth, if it is an issue for you, the "regexp on style string" approach will work only when the background color property is set explicitly on that element. If background color comes from a CSS rule, for example, this approach will not pick it up. Normally, this is the point at which people suggest using `getComputedStyle` or jQuery's `.css()`, which will indeed work (although you'll still get back the `rgb(r,g,b)` format, which if you really want to have in hex format you'll have to convert)--but the question remains, why are you "storing" information in the CSS that you need to get back out again? There are certainly use cases for this, but they are relatively rare.

If you are sure you need to retrieve the background color, from the style on the particular element, and in hex format (why?), then get it and convert it:

```
backgroundColor = select.find(":selected").css('backgroundColor');
rgbColor = convertRGBToHex(style);
```

You can find plenty of approaches to `convertRGBToHex` here on SO or elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```js
  var txt='border:1px solid #00ffff; background-color: #00ffaa;';
var match = txt.match(/background-color ?: ?(#{1}(?:[A-F0-9]){6})(?![0-9A-F])/i);
console.log(match);
document.write(match[1])
```

Comment: What if the hex was written as three digits?